# Descer a página ao reiniciar com JS

Tags: javascript

Estava querendo que quando a página fosse carregada, automaticamente fosse para o fim dela. Não quero usar jquery pois o projeto é algo relativamente simples. Não é necessário. Eu usei o seguinte código:

```
<body onload="toBottom();">

</body>
```

```
function toBottom(){
  var elem = document.querySelector("body");
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

Ele funciona quando carrega página, ok! Só que quando dou refresh não. Apenas se eu fechar a página, e entrar novamente. Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o `onload` dentro do seu `javascript`:

```
window.onload = toBottom;

function toBottom() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente da o mesmo resultado. Funciona, mas não quando da refresh.

Comment: @Ericki mudei aqui a função, com o `setTimeout` funciona

Comment: Perfeito! Thanks^^

Answer (score 4):

Dessa forma testei aqui dando F5 e reload na pagina e funciona perfeitamente.

editei com a função cria br pra n ficar com 30 mil brs na pagina kk

```js
window.onload = function() {
  criaBr();

  toBottom();
};

function criaBr(){
  var body = document.querySelector("body");
  var br = "<br/>";
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      br += br;
  }
  
  body.innerHTML += (br + "<button onclick='refresh()'> Refresh </button>");
}

function refresh(){
 location.reload();
}

function toBottom(){
  var elem = document.querySelector("body");
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

```html
<body>
b


</body>
```

Comment: Na realidade sua solução só funciona porque você está adicionado itens ao `HTML` dentro do `Javascript`. Se você deixar o `HTML` fixo não irá funcionar.

Comment: Funciona sim, se olhar as edições eu havia feito do outro modo, porem para não ficar muito grande o codigo refatorei e fiz assim